# How to convert column from text to date format in MySQL? Current column has multiple date formats

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a dataset that has a start date and end date column, however both columns are currently in text format and are in multiple date formats.

e.g.:

1. `DD-MM-YY`
2. `DD/MM/YYYY`
3. `YYYY-MM-DD`
4. `MM/DD/YYYY`

I want to convert all of these to a standard date format of `DD-MM-YYYY`.

```
2020-11-05   
05-12-2020    
2019-08-07    
20/04/2018    
01-07-2020    
13-05-2019    
11-25-2020
```

Comment: Standard ISO-8601 date format is YYYY-MM-DD, which also is ANSI SQL standard. However, you should alter the column data type to date. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

Comment: here try [this](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

Comment: There is no way you can tell the difference between MM-DD-YYYY and DD-MM-YYYY (which your examples clearly contain).  You will need to reconstruct the data using a single date format.

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN column REGEXP 'regex_pattern1' THEN STR_TO_DATE(column, 'pattern1') CASE ... ELSE NULL END parsed_date, ...`. PS. `01-07-2020` can be Jul 1,2020 or Jan 7, 2020. And I donot see the way to determine what is correct...

Comment: You can assume with 99% accuracy that dates which use `/` as delimiter have the month in front of the day. If this produces illegal date - then treat it as if the day was in front of the month.